# Change the shortcut of cmd+Q for all applications

Tags: macos

I use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> a lot and I don't remember how many times I hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> accidentally.

Is it possible to change the shortcut for quitting applications from <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to something else (not to disallow using keyboard to quit applications), ideally for applications all at once (not to do it for individual application one by one)?

Comment: I thought changing it in the Keyboard section of System Preferences, under Keyboard Shortcuts might work, but it didn't here. Unless I need to reboot to see the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should change the shortcut to ⇧⌘Q for most currently installed applications:

`defaults write -g NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add $(mdfind kMDItemContentType==com.apple.application-bundle | grep -v { |
sed 's/.*\//Quit /g;s/\.app$//g;'"s/'/\\''\\'/g;s/^/'/g;s/$/' '\$@q'/g" | uniq | tr '\n' ' ')`

You could also use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) to change ⌘Q to some other key combination or require holding or pressing it twice to quit an application.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to edit this database visually? That's a crazy command line ninja move you've got there! ;)

Comment: Or can you teach me your ways?

Answer (score 1):

[Howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39520/how-to-change-the-cmdq-shortcut-key-in-os-x-to-stop-accidentally-closing-apps/) devoted a whole article about this subject and they provided an excellent tutorial on how to do this. Basically it comes down to override the default function.

[image]

**BUT** there is a (huge) disadvantage, if you do it that way, you'll have to do this for EVERY application you use, which might work a bit confusing...
So they provide a work-around rather then a solid solution.

Comment: My question mentions that "for applications all at once (not to do it for individual application one by one)".